# Hibernate/JPA - Inserting a generated, non pk/fk, sequence generated column value from parent to child table on saving the parent entity

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa-2.0, one-to-many, cascade

I have a parent entity which has an id column (ID) and non primary but unique column (KEY_ID). This KEY_ID is auto-generated in the Oracle database via sequence.
I have a child entity which has the same KEY_ID column and it is a non primary key column. 
I have a oneTomany asociation between parent and child entities. 
So, When i save the parent, it inserts a record in the child table as well as expected. Im good until this point. But, i also want to save the value of KEY_ID  in the parent table to the KEY_ID column in the child table. Im not sure, whether it is achievable or not. Any help will be much appreciated as i have spent lot of time on this.

````
@Entity
@Table(name = "PARENT")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_GENERATOR1", sequenceName = "SEQNAME1")
public class Parent {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_GENERATOR1")
    @Id
    @Column(name = "PARENT_ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "KEY_ID") // This column is a sequence in the table handled in Oracle.
    private Long keyId; // want to send this column value to the child entity when saving parent entity.

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parent")
    private Set<Child> children;
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "CHILD")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "SEQ_GENERATOR2", sequenceName = "SEQNAME2")
public class Child  {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_GENERATOR2")
    @Id
    @Column(name = "CHILD_ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "KEY_ID")
    private Long keyId; 

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID", nullable=false)
    private Parent parent;
    ...
}```
````

Comment: You can try to do it in a `@PostPersist` callback of the `Parent` entity, but it is not guaranteed to work, as accessing other entities in an entity listener results in undefined behaviour